# Why does the running JavaFX application scene size differ from the scenebuilder preview

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I've got a problem with the view of the application gui in Scene Builder in comparison to running one.

The app UI in the scene builder preview looks like this:
[image: App in scene builder preview looks like that:]

When running the app it looks like that:
[image]

So elements are definitely in different places.

FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>


<BorderPane prefHeight="242.0" prefWidth="465.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8">
   <bottom>
      <Pane prefHeight="242.0" prefWidth="425.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <TextField layoutX="45.0" layoutY="37.0" />
            <TextField layoutX="45.0" layoutY="112.0" />
            <Button layoutX="337.0" layoutY="178.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
         </children>
      </Pane>
   </bottom>
</BorderPane>
```

Main.java:

```
package com.tempapp;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            BorderPane root1 = (BorderPane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("LoginWindows.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root1);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("LoginWindows.fxml").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
        System.out.println("HELLO");
    }
}
```

What is the reason that app looks different? I tried to set the proper height and width values for scene/stage, but it doesn't fix it. Is this caused by java virtual machine, becouse of some resolution scaling? My display is full hd.

Answer (score 1):

In SceneBuilder, set the Max Height and Max Width to `USE_PREF_SIZE`. Likewise, you can also set the min values.

Also, for a scene such as this, BorderPane might be overkill. You could easily use a StackPane with an VBox, or even a GridPane.

!! Edit !!

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="260.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <VBox layoutX="45.0" layoutY="37.0" spacing="12.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <children>
            <TextField fx:id="txtUserName" />
            <TextField fx:id="txtPassword" />
            <HBox>
               <children>
                  <Pane HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                  <Button fx:id="btnOk" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
               </children>
            </HBox>
         </children>
         <padding>
            <Insets bottom="18.0" left="18.0" right="18.0" top="18.0" />
         </padding>
      </VBox>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: I've founded the reason of this situation, Windows scaling sucks, after it is turned off, everythings works fine. Thanks for help!

Comment: It seems to me that if scaling effects your layout so severely, perhaps your layout is not composed properly.  Try using VBox instead of positioning your TextFields using layoutX and layoutY.

Comment: Edited answer with example FXML.