# JavaFX: Node size is different at runtime

Tags: layout, javafx, runtime, size, design-time

I am developing a dialog box inside the scenebuilder and I can see there the size is 625x616 (I am using gridpane), however when I run the tool it looks much bigger (around 900x900).

This is the code I use to load the fxml file

```
 private void DisplayDialog(String title, String fxmlPath) throws IOException {
    final Stage dialog = new Stage();
    dialog.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    dialog.initOwner(primaryStage);
    dialog.setResizable(false);
    dialog.setTitle(title);
    dialog.getIcons().add(primaryStage.getIcons().get(0));
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(fxmlPath));
    Scene dialogScene = new Scene(root);
    dialog.setScene(dialogScene);
    dialog.show();
    logger.exit();
}
```

and here it is my fxml file:

```
<GridPane hgap="5.0" vgap="10.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="ca.mali.dialogs.chapter6.UpdateAttributeValuesServiceController">
<columnConstraints>
<ColumnConstraints hgrow="NEVER" maxWidth="300.0" minWidth="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
<ColumnConstraints hgrow="NEVER" prefWidth="400.0" />
</columnConstraints>
<rowConstraints>
<RowConstraints maxHeight="-Infinity" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
<RowConstraints vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
<RowConstraints maxHeight="-Infinity" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
<RowConstraints maxHeight="-Infinity" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
<RowConstraints maxHeight="-Infinity" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
</rowConstraints>
<padding>
<Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
</padding>
<HBox alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="4">
<Button cancelButton="true" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#Cancel_click" text="Cancel">
<HBox.margin>
<Insets right="20.0" />
</HBox.margin>
</Button>
<Button fx:id="OkButton" defaultButton="true" disable="true" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#OK_click" text="OK" />
</HBox>
<Label text="Instance Name: " GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" />
<ComboBox fx:id="InstanceName" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
<TableView fx:id="AttributeValueTableView" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
<columns>
<TableColumn fx:id="AttributeTableColumn" editable="false" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minWidth="50.0" prefWidth="200.0" text="Attribute" />
<TableColumn fx:id="ValueTableColumn" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minWidth="50.0" prefWidth="400.0" text="Value" />
</columns>
<columnResizePolicy>
<TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
</columnResizePolicy>
</TableView>
<Label text="User-supplied tag*:" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
<TextField fx:id="UserSuppliedTag" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
<Label text="Logical Time:" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
<Spinner fx:id="LogicalTimeSpin" editable="true" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
</GridPane>
```

I also tried to replace Gridpane with VBox but I got the same results.

Comment: This might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33709825/why-does-the-running-javafx-application-scene-size-differ-from-the-scenebuilder

Comment: I tried all suggestions there, but none works for me. I noticed that they solved the problem by turning off "windows scaling". How can I do this?