# JavaFX / FXML UI does not look like it should

Tags: java, javafx-8, scenebuilder

I have a UI I have made using Netbeans and Scene builder using Java FX / FXML. I have never had a problem with it before but for this project for some reason in Scene building my UI would look one way, even the windows preview would look identical to it, but when running it in netbeans it would look messed up. In netbeans, all I am doing is loading and calling it. I have no idea on what the issue can be and nothing is helping on Google.

working screen shot on scene builder and editing and netbeans

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNoYm.jpg

compile and run

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hpo9S.jpg

main.java

```
public class main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       View view = new View();
       view.launch();
    }

}
```

view.java

```
public class View extends Application
{
    @FXML
    private Button login;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) 
    {
        Parent login_page = null;
        try {
            login_page = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLViewLogin.fxml"));
           } 
           catch (IOException ex) 
           {

        }
        primaryStage.setTitle("Welcome!");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(login_page));
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    @FXML
    private void login(ActionEvent event) 
    {}



}
```

FXMLViewLogin.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.net.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="520.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="view.ViewControllerLogin">
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="button1" defaultButton="true" layoutX="74.0" layoutY="296.0" text="Sign Up" />
      <Label layoutX="198.0" layoutY="153.0" text="Password" />
      <Label layoutX="187.0" layoutY="35.0" text="User Name" />
      <TextField fx:id="password" layoutX="74.0" layoutY="204.0" />
      <TextField fx:id="username" layoutX="74.0" layoutY="80.0" />
      <Button fx:id="button" layoutX="323.0" layoutY="296.0" onAction="#login" text="Log In" />
   </children>
</Pane>
```

Comment: This seems to at least be similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33709825/why-does-the-running-javafx-application-scene-size-differ-from-the-scenebuilder

Comment: Don't position everything by hand: you cannot expect that to work if it is displayed in a different-sized window, and obviously SceneBuilder has no knowledge or control over the size of the window that is used in the actual application. Use an appropriate layout pane, e.g. a `VBox` (with perhaps a `BorderPane` to hold the two buttons), or a `GridPane`. See the [layout tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/builtin_layouts.htm#JFXLY102).

Comment: @hotzst your right it is similar, I will take a look thank you

Comment: @James_D Originally, I had done it by hand such as this, but took way longer then I wanted and was much harder, so I did it here expecting it to be easier /: